# Toggle a CSS class in Vue 2.0

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

In vue 1 I was doing this: `v-bind:class='{"isdanger": invalidLogin}'`.

Now I'm trying to do the same in a Vue 2 app but I'm getting this error:

`template syntax error - invalid expression: v-bind:class="{'isdanger': invalidLogin}"`

I'm using `pug`, just in case.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sigh, I changed it to double quotes like this: `v-bind:class="{'is-danger': true}"` and now it works.

Comment: Yes, when nesting: `"` > `'`